# What's the best way to manage sections on a page?

Tags: pages, page-template, content, custom-content, management

I bought some long time ago an HTML theme which was an one-page template, however I'm changing it to be a multiple page, for SEO reasons. Then, my homepage has a lot of sections, containing slideshow, portfolio gallery, testimonials, pricing table, tabs etc.

So, I'm a little bit "lost" about how to manage that and put each content in its respective page, considering the fact that I'm using the Yoast SEO plugin, so SEO here is a huge point.

What would you recommend me about the content management? Should I put each section in a separate file and use the `get_template_part( )` function to include them or cut HTML code and paste it inside the WP wysiwyg editor with all markup? The most important is that I need to have the possibility of editing that content from admin.

What would you suggest me??

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the possibility of editing that content from admin and it should be SEO friendly and you are using Yoast? Right?

Then I think [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) is the best way to do your task. You can change the content from Admin panel (I assume that you mean the code as a content.). It can be easily set title, meta description using Yoast plugin to templates files to.

Comment: Great! But I should paste the HTML in the WP editor, right?